# jQuery complex selector : Hierarchy string variable

Tags: jquery-selectors

assume in #main div the table have id foo_userId which represent contents of user have id userId

I have to select table with userId 1234 with given id as variable

```
<div id="main">
    <table id="foo_1234_m"></table>    //select this 
    <table id="f0006458_m"></table>
    <table id="f0001234_n"></table>
    <table id="foo_9999_k"></table>        
</div>


$('div#main>table#foo_1234_m')
// foo : string , 1234 : variable , m variable
 //////////i'm trying something like :

var userId='1234'                   
var tableID='foo_' + userId          // from this

$("div#main>table[id^='foo_1234']")    // how to make this
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have the correct selector syntax. So you can write the jQuery selector using the same string concatenation as in your example, e.g.:

```
var userId = '1234'
var tableId = 'foo_' + userId
var element = $("div#main>table[id^='" + tableId + "']")
```